# Adding System.Data.SQLite reference in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

Hi I have added the sqlite dll's to my project in a folder but when I add the using statement it does not pick it up and if I try to add a new reference, there is no option for sqlite. Is there something else i should do after adding the dll's?

Comment: Where did you get that dlls from? Try to install it via nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `Browse` button in the `Add references`-dialog, where you can select the SQLite.dll, but I would recommend using NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/

Comment: Thank you so much , used NuGet.